# How to read array in $_POST in PHP

Tags: php, forms, post, scope

OK this is my script:-

```
<form action="results.php" method="post">
          <?php mysql_select_db($database, $databasename) or die("Opps some things went wrong");
          $sqlQueryTestDisplay = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM questions WHERE test_id='$testtaken_id' ORDER BY question_id ASC");
          $i = 0;
          while($DisplayItems = mysql_fetch_array($sqlQueryTestDisplay))
          {
              $i = $i + 1;
              $question_id = $DisplayItems['question_id'];
              $question = $DisplayItems['question'];
              $opta = $DisplayItems['opta'];
              $optb = $DisplayItems['optb'];
              $optc = $DisplayItems['optc'];
              $optd = $DisplayItems['optd'];
              $answer[$i] = $DisplayItems['answer'];
              $thisAnswer = $answer[$i];
              echo '<li>'.$question.'</li>';
              echo '<p>';
              echo '<label><input type="radio" name="optans'.$i.'" value="radio" id="RadioGroup'.$i.'_0" />'.$opta.'</label>';
              echo '<label><input type="radio" name="optans'.$i.'" value="radio" id="RadioGroup'.$i.'_1" />'.$optb.'</label>';
              echo '<label><input type="radio" name="optans'.$i.'" value="radio" id="RadioGroup'.$i.'_2" />'.$optc.'</label>';
              echo '<label><input type="radio" name="optans'.$i.'" value="radio" id="RadioGroup'.$i.'_3" />'.$optd.'</label>';
              echo '<input name="ans'.$i.'" type="hidden" value="'.$thisAnswer.'" />';
              echo '</p>';
          }
          echo '<input name="total_questions" type="hidden" value="'.$i.'" />';
          echo '<input name="test_id" type="hidden" value="'.$TestID.'" />';
          ?>
          <input name="submittest" type="submit" />
          </form>
```

As you can see i am using array to store values in different fields. Now on the next page i.e on my result.php page I am writing this:-

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submittest'])) 
{
global $ans1;
$TotalQuestions = $_POST['total_questions'];
$TestID = $_POST['test_id'];
$TestResult = 0;
for ($i=1; $i<=$TotalQuestions; $i++)
{
    $ansValue = 'ans'.$i;
    $optansValue = 'optans'.$i;
    $ans = $_POST[$ansValue];
    $optans = $_POST[$optansValue];
    if ($ans == $optans)
    {
        $TestResult = $TestResult + 1;
    }
}
$st_id = $row_Recordset1['id'];
mysql_select_db($database, $databasename) or die("Opps some things went wrong");
$sqlQueryInsertResult = mysql_query("INSERT INTO results (student_id, test_id, test_result) VALUES ('$st_id', '$TestID', '$TestResult')");
header('location:results.php'); 
}
?>
```

Now my script is not reading ans1, ans2.....and so on AND even quesans1, quesans2.....and so on.

I think problem is in the way i am calling the array using the $_POST method.

Is the syntax correct, how can i FIX it... Please help :|

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but... are you including the *answer* to your questions in the HTML? If so, the user will be able to see all the answers by viewing the page's source!

Comment: Add name="submittest" to the <form> tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of your radio buttons are returning "radio" as their value. Make them return the answer and you should be OK
Change your radio definitions to:

```
'<INPUT type="radio" name="optans'.$i.'" value="'.$opta.'" >'.$opta.'</INPUT>'
'<INPUT type="radio" name="optans'.$i.'" value="'.$optb.'" >'.$optb.'</INPUT>'
'<INPUT type="radio" name="optans'.$i.'" value="'.$optc.'" >'.$optc.'</INPUT>'
'<INPUT type="radio" name="optans'.$i.'" value="'.$optd.'" >'.$optd.'</INPUT>'
```

Might be worth not putting the answer onto the page as a hidden field - makes a quiz quite easy. Do another SQL query to check the answers when they come back

Use some more loops to display the radio buttons and you can shorten your code a bit.

Answer (score 1):

0Change your test options to this:

```
         echo '<label><input type="radio" name="optans'.$i.'[]" value="1" id="RadioGroup'.$i.'_0" />'.$opta.'</label>';
          echo '<label><input type="radio" name="optans'.$i.'[]" value="2" id="RadioGroup'.$i.'_1" />'.$optb.'</label>';
          echo '<label><input type="radio" name="optans'.$i.'[]" value="3" id="RadioGroup'.$i.'_2" />'.$optc.'</label>';
          echo '<label><input type="radio" name="optans'.$i.'[]" value="4" id="RadioGroup'.$i.'_3" />'.$optd.'</label>';
```

and your processor to this:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submittest'])) 
{
global $ans1;
$TotalQuestions = $_POST['total_questions'];
$TestID = $_POST['test_id'];
$TestResult = 0;
for ($i=1; $i<=$TotalQuestions; $i++)
{
    $ans = $_POST['ans'.$i];
    $optans = $_POST['optans'.$i];

    for ($j=0;$j<count($optans);$j++) { 
         if ($optans[$j]==$ans) { 
             $TestResult = $TestResult + 1;               
         }
    }
}
```

This is a very insecure way to compare test answers.  Someone could easily View Source and see the correct answers.  You should validate the test answers after the `$_POST`